# Retrieve a set of records with SQL, then order them using Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2 and MariaDB. My table has 500,000 rows. In usual query, we will add the `order` clause in it, like this:

```
# takes 4000ms to load, returns 100 records
@shops = Shop.where(:shop_type => 'fashion').order('overall_rating DESC')
```

If we remove the `order`, the load time is greatly reduced:

```
# takes 20ms to load, returns 100 records
@shops = Shop.where(:shop_type => 'fashion')
```

Is it possible to first retrieve the `@shops` 100 records, then use Rails to order them by `overall_rating DESC` without involving SQL? Or, separate the queries to 2 parts: first retrieve 100 records, then order that set of records. This can greatly improve the performance.

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `overall_rating`

Comment: Already indexed. I am trying a different solution for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727363/retrieve-a-set-of-records-with-sql-then-order-them-using-rails

Comment: @Victor - That is a self-referencing link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sorting a collection is part of Ruby's [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) mixin.

```
@shops = Shop.where(:shop_type => 'fashion')
@shops.sort! { |a,b| b.overall_rating <=> a.overall_rating }
```