# Includes association of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2, I have the following original code:

```
nearby_spots = current_spot.nearbys(10, :order => 'overall_rating 
DESC').where(:spot_type => spot_type).includes(:photos).first(5)
```

For some performance reasons, I have to separate the code to the following:

```
# retrieve all records without any order
x = current_spot.nearbys(10, :order => false).where(:spot_type => spot_type)

# sort by overall_rating using Rails instead of SQL, and take first 5
nearby_spots = (x.sort! { |a,b| b.overall_rating <=> a.overall_rating }).first(5)
```

The `nearby_spots` is an array of objects. How do I eager load the `photos` like the original? `.includes` only work on a class, not array.

Comment: `includes` works also on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but since you called `sort!` on your relation, it became `Array`. So the question is: Why do you think this way of sorting is more efficient than appropriate SQL query, like in your first approach?

Comment: The original problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727131/rails-order-by-overall-rating-is-slow-for-large-set-of-records Then I have to not let SQL to take over the sorting because I have 500,000 rows of data (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727363/retrieve-a-set-of-records-with-sql-then-order-them-using-rails?noredirect=1#comment31054014_20727363) and it's slow in sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preloader`, add this line:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(nearby_spots, :photos).run()
```